# change tooltip name(current & previous) in google diff chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-visualization

I want to create a google diff chart for a survey. that will show the total number of user and survey given users.
My javascript code is:-

```
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
    var overallData = [];
    var givenData = [];
    overallData.push(['Department', 'Total Users']);
    givenData.push(['Department', 'Given feedback']);
    for (var i in data) {
        overallData.push([data[i].department_name, data[i].emp_count]);
        givenData.push([data[i].department_name, data[i].upward_done]);
    }
    var oldData = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(overallData);
    var newData = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(givenData);
    var colChartDiff = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('feedback_dept_chart'));
    var options = {
        fontName: 'Calibri',
        legend: 'none',
        height: 200,
        width: 960,
        vAxis: {title: 'No of employee'},
        tooltip: {isHtml: false}
    };
    var diffData = colChartDiff.computeDiff(oldData, newData);
    colChartDiff.draw(diffData, options);
```

And data is :-

```
[{"department_name":"Design","emp_count":1,"upward_done":1},
 {"department_name":"Management","emp_count":1,"upward_done":0},
 {"department_name":"Technology","emp_count":3,"upward_done":2}]
```

The problem with diff chart is it is showing tooltip named "current" and "previous". And I want to change it by "total users" and "survey given users".

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Would you please post full code with script,?,

Comment: It'll be batter to helping you

Comment: @shivam Is this fixed

Comment: Not Yet @yasar-arafath

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add below code for tooltip into **options**

```
    diff: { 
            oldData: { opacity: 1, color: 'yellow',
                 tooltip:{
                    prefix:'Label 1'
                    } 
                  }, 
            newData: { opacity: 1, widthFactor: 1,
                 tooltip:{
                    prefix:'Label 2'
                    }
                 }
          }
```

Comment: @ShivamPandey Ok glad to know it worked for you. Please accept and mark my answer to right for you.